Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.24. React Native Async Storage
Error when building release or debug
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-async-storage'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':@react-native-async-storage:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.24.
     Required by:
         project :@react-native-async-storage
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.24:
          - gradle70JavadocElements
          - gradle70RuntimeElements
          - gradle70SourcesElements
          - gradle71JavadocElements
          - gradle71RuntimeElements
          - gradle71SourcesElements
          - gradle74JavadocElements
          - gradle74RuntimeElements

I tried updating the version async storage, but didn´t work
